# ReturnUrl is null in ASP.NET Core login

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc

I have ASP.NET Core application with individual accounts; very similar to what gets generated by VS2017. For testing purposes I put `[Authorize]` attribute on `About()` action in Home controller. I am redirected to Login page as expected, and I see that URL is `http://localhost:5000/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FAbout` - also as expected. However, in the POST Login method ReturnUrl is null. I have Login method in Account Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model) {
...
}
```

I also tried `ReturnUrl` as parameter explicitly, with or without `[FromQuery]`. In all permutations it is null.

Comment: do you use new {ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] } in @Html.BeginForm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be sure that you are using

```
Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new {ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] })


[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputModel model, string ReturnUrl) {
...
}
```

Comment: The view was generated with taghelpers: `<form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post">` When I changed `@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]` to `@Model.ReturnUrl` it started working. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: in my case the issue was, I used asp tag helper in the form that container asp-for action and controller. I removed this tags and the value for returnUrl stared appearing in my controller login method.

Answer (score 4):

This is how i managed to get mine working

The Get Action

```
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ViewBag.ReturnUrl))
                    return Redirect(ViewBag.ReturnUrl);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return View();
        }
```

My Form is like this :

```
  <form asp-action="Login" method="post" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewBag.ReturnUrl" >
```

The post action :

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(VMLogin model, string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

     //Authentication here 
  
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ViewBag.ReturnUrl))
        return Redirect(ViewBag.ReturnUrl);

 
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For .net core this is how you can fix the issue.

In your View,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { returnUrl = Context.Request.Query["ReturnUrl"] }))
```

In your Controller,

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login(YourViewModel m, string returnUrl = null)
{
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
 {
  return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
 }
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first you must get return url in get method like this :

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    TempData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

get returnUrl as parameter in get method and send in to post method by tempdata.

the post method also like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    //Your Login Code ...

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TempData["ReturnUrl"] as string) && Url.IsLocalUrl(TempData["ReturnUrl"] as string))
    {
        return Redirect(TempData["ReturnUrl"] as string);
    }

    return RedirectToAction(controllerName:"Home",actionName:"Index");
    }
```